# Backbone model remove undefined attribute on set

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have backbone model : {id:1232, defaultColor:value1, customColor:value2} and I want to update this model to {id:1234, defaultColor:value3} without custom attribute, on calling set on this model - updated model looks like this {id:1234, defaultColor:value3, custom: value2}. 
Is there a way to remove custom attribute if it is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone model has method `.unset` ([doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-unset)). You can write something like `model.unset('customColor')`

Updated (see comments):

You can add `parse` method to your model

```
parse: function (response) {
    if (response['customColor'] === undefined)
        this.attributes['customColor'] = undefined;
    return response;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't want to call unset on model because I have Collection which contains these model and I am updating entire collection. And also I need not unset customColor always because I want to unset customer color only when it is undefined in model.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, «attribute is undefined» and «model does not have attribute» are the same things. So you need not do anything to remove nonexistent attribute.

Comment: When I update the model, the customColor attribute is not present in my JSONObject so after updating id and defaultColor is changed to new values but old cutomColor is retained in model.Basically what I need is a way to unset a model-attribute in all the models of a collection. Looks like I need to iterate through each model and unset cutomColor in them.